# 'Class' does not contain a definition for 'Method'

Tags: c#, asp.net, methods

In class `Employee` I've got some methods, which work fine. Now I wanted to add new method, for example

```
public void ExampleMethod()
{         
}
```

Then I call it

```
Employee employee = new Employee();
employee.ExampleMethod();
```

ExampleMethod is present in IntelliSense displayed after dot, when I hit F12 it also redirect me to that method, but while starting project I've got an error: 'Employee' does not contain a definition for 'ExampleMethod' and no extension method 'ExampleMethod' accepting a first argument of type 'Employee' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

I don't know why this error is caused, because all other earlier methods work fine. What's the problem?

Comment: can you post your full employee class? Clean + rebuild all might help

Comment: Try manually update your assembly in GAC

Comment: Clean and Rebuild worked! Thank you very much :D

Answer (score 27, accepted):

There are three possibilities:

1. If you are referring an old DLL then it can't be used. So you have to refer to a new DLL.
2. If you are using it in a different namespace and trying to use the other namespace's dll then it won't refer to this method.
3. You may need to rebuild the project.

I think third option might be the cause for you. Please post more information in order to understand exact problem of yours.

Comment: 4) The OP may have got confused with some sort of class ambiguity and referenced an incorrect Employee class from a different assemply/project? +1.

Comment: +1 -> Don't name your Entity Framework Database tables the same as classes... Doh.

Comment: I just had to clean and rebuild

Comment: I had to clean and rebuild the solution, not only the project.

Answer (score 6):

Create class with namespace name might resovle your issue

```
namespace.Employee employee = new namespace.Employee(); 
employee.ExampleMethod();
```

Comment: I manually added the namespace before every class call. This worked for me.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. Turns out the project I was referencing did not get build.
When I went to the build configuration manager in visual studio and enabled the reference project , the issue got resolved.

Answer (score 2):

If you are using a class from another project, the project needs to re-build and create re-the dll. Make sure "Build" is checked for that project on 
**Build -> Configuration Manager** in **Visual Studio**. So the reference project will re-build and update the dll.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem. I changed the Version of Assembly in `AssemblyInfo.cs` in the Properties Folder. But, I don't have any idea why this problem happened. Maybe the compiler doesn't understand that this `dll` is newer, just changing the version of Assembly.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this problem; the issue seems different from the other answers posted here, so I'll mention it in case it helps someone.

In my case, I have an internal base class defined in one assembly ("A"), an internal derived class defined in a second assembly ("B"), and a test assembly ("TEST").  I exposed internals defined in assembly "B" to "TEST" using `InternalsVisibleToAttribute`, but neglected to do so for assembly "A".  This produced the error mentioned at top with no further indication of the problem; using `InternalsVisibleToAttribute` to expose assembly "A" to "TEST" resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when working in a solution with multiple projects that share code.
Turned out that I forgot to update the DLL in the folder of the 2nd project.

My suggestion is to take a good look at the 'project' column in the Error list window and make sure that project also uses the right DLL.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion about the project column.

In ASP.NET, Global.asax is considered in a different project than the rest of your code, it seems? So you cannot call internal/friend methods from Global.asax. Very annoying.

Answer (score 0):

Today I encountered a problem with the exact same symptoms as you describe. I closed all files and restarted VS only to find out that some files *disappeared* from the Solution Explorer.

The following solved my problem: by selecting the current project in the Solution Explorer, a little icon `Show all files` appears on the top bar. Right-clicking the file and selecting `Include In Project` does the thing.

[Credit](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/82d5ef6e-c64c-445b-9f46-f648ff3ce6aa/file-missing-from-solution-explorer?forum=tfsversioncontrol)

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem, "Rebuild Solution" and then "Clean Solution" didn't work.I solved that by  checking  my DLL references.

Answer (score 0):

When I had the same error,

```
dotnet restore
```

Resolved it.  From the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/tools/dotnet-restore):

> `dotnet restore` - Restores the dependencies and tools of a project.