# 'Class' does not contain a definition for 'Method' -- C# public static method call from .dll

Tags: c#, dll, visual-studio-2013, static-methods

I read through [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475142/class-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-method) to no avail. *For the sake of this question, I've tried to simplify my code while still demonstrating the issue.*

I have a solution in Visual Studio 2013 with two projects. One is `MyWebApp`, the other contains a public static class that converts units, which is used by the `MyWebApp` as a `.dll` file. Today, I added a new public static method to the units converter.

```
namespace UnitsConverter
{
  static public class Converter
  {
    ...
    public static bool Standardize(string have, out string std){ ... }
  }
}
```

And then I rebuilt the `UnitsConverter` project and replaced the old `UnitsConverter.dll` in `MyWebApp`'s bin file with the newly generated one.

Then, after rebuilding `MyWebApp`, I try to use the method:

```
using UnitsConverter;
public class RecordsUploader 
{
  ...
  public bool cleanUnits()
  {
    ...
    Converter.Standardize(...);
  }
}
```

Alas, no matter what I do, I keep getting `'UnitsConverter.Converter' does not contain a definition for 'Standardize'`

Comment: "replaced the old UnitsConverter.dll in MyWebApp's bin file with the newly generated one." - What about reference to that dll ? It seems like you are missing reference to that particular dll. If you already have the reference then remove it and add it again. This should solve it.

Comment: try check reference path from solution

Comment: Recycle your app pool. IIS is smart enough to reload the assemblies that have changed, but it can only do that at the top level (dependencies are not reloaded). It's still using the previous version of `UnitsConverter.dll`.

Comment: Thank you all! @Habib I tried your solution first and it worked. Thanks!