# assembly that is not referenced error

Tags: c#, asp.net, google-api, google-drive-api, google-api-dotnet-client

Hi Friends i am working over first time with google api for authentication and uploading file to google spreadsheet with asp.net. can any one help with errors i am getting as:

> Error 1   The type 'Google.Apis.Http.IHttpUnsuccessfulResponseHandler'
>   is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.6.0.16897,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> Error 2   The type 'Google.Apis.Authentication.IAuthenticator' is
>   defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a
>   reference to assembly 'Google.Apis, Version=1.6.0.16897,
>   Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=null'.
>
> Error 3   'Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer' does not
>   contain a definition for
>   'Authenticator'
>
> Error 4   'Google.Apis.Drive.v2.DriveService' does not contain a
>   definition for
>   'Scopes'

My Code is below:-

```
using System;

using System.Diagnostics;

using DotNetOpenAuth.OAuth2;

using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2;

using Google.Apis.Authentication.OAuth2.DotNetOpenAuth;

using Google.Apis.Drive.v2;

using Google.Apis.Drive.v2.Data;

using Google.Apis.Util;

using Google.Apis.Services;

public partial class CS : System.Web.UI.Page
{

    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }

    protected void UploadFile(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        if (FileUpload1.HasFile)
        {
            Session["File"] = FileUpload1.PostedFile;
            Session["Description"] = txtDescription.Text;

            String CLIENT_ID = "YOUR_CLIENT_ID";
            String CLIENT_SECRET = "YOUR_CLIENT_SECRET";

            // Register the authenticator and create the service
            var provider = new NativeApplicationClient(GoogleAuthenticationServer.Description, CLIENT_ID, CLIENT_SECRET);
            var auth = new OAuth2Authenticator<NativeApplicationClient>(provider, GetAuthorization);
           var service = new DriveService(new BaseClientService.Initializer()
            {
                Authenticator = auth
            });

            File body = new File();
            body.Title = "My document";
            body.Description = "A test document";
            body.MimeType = "text/plain";

            byte[] byteArray = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes("document.txt");
            System.IO.MemoryStream stream = new System.IO.MemoryStream(byteArray);

            FilesResource.InsertMediaUpload request = service.Files.Insert(body, stream, "text/plain");
            request.Upload();

            File file = request.ResponseBody;
            Console.WriteLine("File id: " + file.Id);
            Console.WriteLine("Press Enter to end this process.");
            Console.ReadLine();
        }


    }


   public IAuthorizationState GetAuthorization(NativeApplicationClient arg)
        {
            // Get the auth URL:
            IAuthorizationState state = new AuthorizationState(new[] { DriveService.Scopes.Drive.GetStringValue() });
            state.Callback = new Uri(NativeApplicationClient.OutOfBandCallbackUrl);
            Uri authUri = arg.RequestUserAuthorization(state);

            // Request authorization from the user (by opening a browser window):
            Process.Start(authUri.ToString());
            Console.Write("  Authorization Code: ");
            string authCode = Console.ReadLine();
            Console.WriteLine();

            // Retrieve the access token by using the authorization code:
            return arg.ProcessUserAuthorization(authCode, state);
        }



}
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of ['Class' does not contain a definition for 'Method'](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12475142/class-does-not-contain-a-definition-for-method)

Comment: Are those errors in visual studio or in runtime only? If they are at compile time, it seems pretty obvious that you are missing the Google dlls.
  If at runtime, then you probably have them in the development env bin but are not copied over to iis. Try adding the reference and check "copy" in the assembly's properties.
Finally, you might be running the Web app inside a pool that has a .net version that is too low to load the dlls. 
Good luck!